# Fingerprint reader on Asus Zenbook

Tags: ubuntu, asus, zorin, fingerprint, zenbook

So I have `ZorinOS` installed on my `ASUS ZenBook UX330UA-AH54`, however, `FingerprintGUI` shows my fingerprint sensor (`Elantech` I think) as an unknown device. Is there any custom software or fixes that can be used to get my laptop to pickup the `fingerprint sensor`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your device's ID against the supported list ([from the developer's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui)):

```
  Supported readers (run command lsusb to find out the ID of your reader)

  https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html and

  0483:2015    147e:1003    147e:3000
  0483:2016    147e:2015    147e:3001
  147e:1000    147e:2016    147e:5002
  147e:1001    147e:2020    147e:5003
  147e:1002
```

If yours is supported, run through their installation and troubleshooting steps on that Launchpad page.

Answer (score 0):

No support yet! You can follow this bug report on Launchpad & subscribe to it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290

Of course make sure to check your device id using `lsusb` & verify that it is **04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp** before subscribing!